# Localize images in 3 space

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

Just a quick question if anyone knew how you would localize multiple images to each other in 3 space. The images are taken from a car so I would want to localize the camera with respect to the car and horizon and then I would want to localize them with respect to the world. Any suggestions or directions would be greatly appreciated.

The official instructions are as follows:

> In the pics directory, you'll find 5 short "videos" with 10 frames each of driving the same set of road. Different cars, different mountings, etc...
>
> Your goal, write a program to localize them all with respect to each other in 3 space. You may first want to localize the camera w.r.t to the car and the horizon before w.r.t to the world.
>
> Deliverables:
>     Transformation matrices from each camera to world
>     A script to transform images into each other :)

I prefer to write in C# since that is the language I am currently learning, but willing to learn other languages as well.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/

Comment: @James, So did you manage to get into comma.ai?

Comment: @Pacerier, no I never applied haha. I stopped looking at this actually. I was part of their beta program for the comma one with the chffr app. However, after countless overheating of my s7 edge and no real direct benefit (i.e. my car not supported nor ever going to be supported, I drive a Ford C-max with no sensing) I stopped using the chffr app as well.